# prolog function extraction from the code

Tags: prolog

I have a question regarding prolog code that I did and i need your help please. I write this code

```
picture(1,middle(C,C)).
picture(2,northwest(C,C)).
picture(3,northeast(C,C)).
picture(4,middle(S,S)).
picture(5,northwest(S,S)).
picture(6,northeast(S,S)).
picture(7,southeast(S,S)).
```

if I have picture 1,3 and I want the relation between them so  picture1 is in middle and picture 3 is in northeast and given third picture I want to find the fourth picture depend on the relation between 1 and 3:

```
find_picture((1,3),(6,P)).
```

In this case P=4 because the relation is middle. So, how I can get the function name from the given picture?

Comment: what about if I do it like: picture(1,middle,C,C).
picture(2,northwest,C,C).
picture(3,northeast,C,C).
picture(4,middle,S,S).
picture(5,northwest,S,S).
picture(6,northeast,S,S).
picture(7,southeast,S,S).

Comment: find_picture((A,B),(C,D)):- picture(A,Relation1,alpha1,alpha1), picture(B,Relation2,alpha1,alpha1), picture(C,Relation1,alpha2,alpha2), picture(C,Relation2,alpha2,alpha2). is that right?

Answer (score 1):

in Prolog we write relations among arguments. From your description, this could be a start

```
find_picture((A,B),(C,D)) :-
    picture(A,P),
    picture(B,Q),
    picture(C,Q),
    picture(D,P).
```

yields

```
?- find_picture((1,3),(6,X)).
X = 1 ;
X = 4.
```

Note there are 2 solutions - the one you don't expect can be ruled out adding a comparison

```
find_picture((A,B),(C,D)) :-
    picture(A,P),
    picture(B,Q),
    picture(C,Q),
    picture(D,P),
    D\=A.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. but just a question regarding P in this example is between (C,C) and B is between (C,C) but C is between (S,S) and D should be between (S,S) how that can be done?

Comment: Also, in other example C maybe equal to C and B may equal to D how that can be done?

Comment: My answer wasn't really helpful, because I glissed over an important point. Where you wrote - for instance - `picture(1,middle(C,C)).`, C is *unspecified* (can take any value). You should update your question at least with an actual entry you need to handle. I guess it will be something like `picture(1,middle(100,200)).`

Comment: what about if I update my code to be it like picture(1,middle,C,C) picture(2,northwest,C,C).. and so on.is that an efficient way to do so?

Comment: What is `C` ? A number ? Anyway, don't worry about efficiency before stating a clear logic representation.

Comment: no C is a shape called the alphabet C. so if the relation is the location of the alphabet C to the other alphabet C.

Comment: what about if I do it like: picture(1,middle,C,C). picture(2,northwest,C,C). picture(3,northeast,C,C). picture(4,middle,S,S). picture(5,northwest,S,S). picture(6,northeast,S,S). picture(7,southeast,S,S).

Comment: find_picture((A,B),(C,D)):- picture(A,Relation1,alpha1,alpha1), picture(B,Relation2,alpha1,alpha1), picture(C,Relation1,alpha2,alpha2), picture(C,Relation2,alpha2,alpha2). is that right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think may help zou but without the code for find_picture I can not go into further detail:

```
picture(1,middle(C,C)).

?- picture(N, Relation), Relation =.. [Name|_], Name = middle.
N = 1,
Relation = middle(_G22, _G22),
Name = middle.
```

the Name of the relation is `middle`.